# How can I convert a long into a list of digits?

Tags: c#

I have a long number that I want to convert to a list of integers corresponding to decimal digits.

```
long l = 9876543210L;

List<int> list = //  how?
```

Expecetd result: `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` so `list[0]` will be 9, `list[1]` will be 8 (2nd digit from the left), etc.

Comment: **Compare this question to the original this one duplicates, which got four upvotes and an answer with 11 upvotes**

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I had some comments on my answer and now they are gone. Were they deleted by a mod? Is there some policy I'm unaware of?

Comment: @DrewNoakes: They were deleted by a mod.  None of them were particularly relevant to your answer's content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy to do this via string processing, you could use:

```
long l = ...;

var list = l.ToString().Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())).ToList();
```

This converts the number to a string (in decimal), then parses each character in the string as an integer.

If performance is critical, you're better off doing this numerically.